# Converting an image to black and white

Tags: python, performance

This code is a project that I am working on to eventually analyze some images but right now I am purely trying to read an image and convert it to black and white.  The input should be either white or something else which would end up as black so it is easy to check for this.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np

img = mpimg.imread('./Training/Image1.png')

imgplot = plt.imshow(img)

width = img.shape[1]
height = img.shape[0]

def generateArray():
    arr = []
    for y in range(img.shape[0]):
        arr.append([])
        for x in range(img.shape[1]):
            if img[y][x][0] != 1:
                arr[y].append(1)
            else:
                arr[y].append(0)
    return arr

arr = generateArray()

plt.show()
```

To be clear, I desire to create an array `arr` that contains either a 0 if the corresponding pixel in the inputted image is white or 1 if it is anything other than white.

I am somewhat of a beginner with Python but I am confused as to why this code takes so long to run (>19 seconds on my older Mac).  Is there something that I am missing that would speed it up significantly?

Comment: "anything other than white" - are you sure? This will make most images completely black. The usual thing to do is set the output white if the average of all input channels is above 0.5.

Comment: @Reinderien yes, eventually that is probably my goal but right now all of my images are B/W RGB images so all I have to do is check if the pixel is white.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there are a few things which can be done to speed up your code.

You create local variables `width` and `height`.  But then you don't use these variables.  Instead you use `for x in range(img.shape[1]):` which ends up evaluating `img.shape[1]` a total of `height` times.  Consider that `img.shape` retrieves the shape array from `img`, and then accesses the `[1]` member of that list.  Using `for x in range(width):` doesn't have that overhead.

Consider `arr[y].append(_)`.  Again, this code is looking up in the `arr` list, the `[y]` element, and to that retrieved list appending a value.  That done once for every pixel.  If you kept a handle to the list that you are appending to, you wouldn't have to look it up each time.

```
def generateArray():
    arr = []
    for y in range(height):
        row = []
        for x in range(width):
            if img[y][x][0] != 1:
               row.append(1)
            else:
               row.append(0)
        arr.append(row)
    return arr
```

The above code should be a little faster.

Appending is a time-consuming operation.  If the `list` is stored as an array, rather than a linked-list, then appending an element will require frequent reallocation of the array capacity, and copying of all of the elements to the new storage area.  We can prevent this reallocating and copying by allocating storage for all of the data all at once:

```
def generateArray():
    arr = [None] * height          # Correctly sized array of rows
    for y in range(height):
        row = [0] * width          # Correctly sized row, filled with 0's
        for x in range(width):
            if img[y][x][0] != 1:
               row[x] = 1
        arr[y] = row
    return arr
```

Here, the `row` array starts off with `[0, 0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]` so it is only necessary to set the elements to `1` where needed.

---

Looping and list lookup can be slow.  Consider:

```
        for x in range(width):
            if img[y][x][0] != 1:
                row[x] = 1
```

which loops over all the `x` values of a row, and for every `x` value, looks up the row `img[y]`, and then the pixel in the row `img[y][x]`, for each pixel in that row, and then accesses the `[0]` element of that pixel.  That's a lot of lookups.  If instead we used:

```
        for x, pixel in enumerate(img[y]):
            if pixel[0] != 1:
                row[x] = 1
```

we'd be iterating over the row of pixels, getting their values without the double list lookup.

We could also use list comprehension to build the list.  Since each row is of a fixed, known length, the list comprehension can allocate the correctly sized list, and fill in the elements one-at-a-time, without indexing or appending.

```
def generateArray():
    arr = [None] * height
    for y in range(height):
        arr[y] = [ 1 if pixel[0] != 1 else 0 for pixel in img[y] ]
    return arr
```

That also applies to building each row.

```
def generateArray():
    return [ [ 1 if pixel[0] != 1 else 0 for pixel in row ] for row in img ]
```

---

The function `generateArray()` uses a global variable `img`.  It would be better to pass `img` into the function.

```
def generateArray(img):
    # code which uses img
```

---

`generateArray()` is a terrible name for the function.  Maybe `generateMaskFromImage()`?

---

The output `arr` is not being used by your code.  If you omitted the line:

```
arr = generateArray()
```

your code would run much, much faster.   ;-)

Comment: Absolutely excellent answer!  I’ll hold off on accepting this answer for a little while to allow others to answer but this answers everything I was looking for.

Comment: Glad you like the answer.  And also glad you aren’t accepting it.  You `import numpy` and there is probably a 1-line `numpy` answer that is faster than my solution, possibly clearer to read, and will result in a more memory efficient structure than my double list comprehension answer.

Answer (score 5):

While [the answer by](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/209954/98493) [@AJNeufeld](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/100620/ajneufeld) correctly explains the shortcomings regarding normal Python in your code, there is indeed a faster way using `numpy`.

First, you can build a mask of all pixels that have the value 1:

```
mask = (img == [1, 1, 1]).all(axis=-1)
```

This mask is already the same as the output of your `generateArray`.

Executing your function takes about 720 ms ± 17.9 ms on my machine with some image file I had lying around (PNG, 471 x 698 pixels), whereas the generation of this mask is a hundred times faster at 7.37 ms ± 96.6 µs.

Now we construct two images, one completely black and one completely white:

```
black = np.zeros_like(img)
white = np.ones_like(img)
```

And then you can use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to conditionally on the `mask` use those two images:

```
img_bw = np.where(mask[:,:,None], white, black)
```

The weird looking slicing with `None` just makes sure that the mask has the right dimensionality (i.e. three values per pixel, instead of just one).

Putting it all together:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np

def to_bw(img):
    """Return a black and white copy of `img`.

    Pixels which are white in the original image stay white,
    all other pixels are turned black.
    """
    mask = (img == [1, 1, 1]).all(axis=-1)
    black = np.zeros_like(img)
    white = np.ones_like(img)
    return np.where(mask[:,:,None], white, black)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    img = mpimg.imread('./Training/Image1.png')
    img_bw = to_bw(img)
    plt.imshow(img_bw)
    plt.show()
```

The whole `to_bw` function only takes 14 ms ± 324 µs.

Comment: a perf comparison would be nice, but other than that, this is a great answer.

Comment: @OscarSmith: Added some timings, for some random smallish png file using `numpy` to generate the mask is about a hundred times faster.

Comment: The `np.where` and weird looking slicing can be avoided with: `arr = np.zeros_like(img)` and `arr[mask] = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]`

Comment: @JanKuiken Yes, I had also tried that when I wrote the answer. Interestingly this was about 50% slower with my image.